# PHP inverse function for base_convert?

Tags: php

I have to do arithmetic with some ternary (base 3) numbers. I know I can use base_convert to get from a ternary string ("2001022210") to an integer. Is there an existing function to do the inverse?

I want "some_function" such that:

```
$someInteger = base_convert("2001022210", 10, 3);
some_function($someInteger);
```

answers "2001022210". I'm happy to provide extra arguments ...

```
some_function($someInteger, 3);
some_function($someInteger, 3, 10);
```

I know I can code this myself, but I'm hoping it's already there.

Comment: Are you joking? Am I going to have to type this out? I guess... `base_convert($someinteger, 3, 10);`

Comment: Isn't the first argument to base convert a string? Ah ... it gets converted automatically. Duh.

Comment: @Sammitch how about this gist: https://gist.github.com/sevgilisedat/fbeadb2f504f8d1ccb67

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$someInteger` is now in base 3... so just do `$base10Int = base_convert($someInteger, 3, 10);` to get it back.

Comment: I'm new to php, and still not used to its automatic argument conversion. Sorry for the stupid question, thanks for the low-key answer.

Comment: No problem, everyone's new at some point. Remember to accept the answer if it solved your problem!

Answer (score 1):

Tom. Please head over to http://php.net/ when you use php functions to see what they actually do. Reading and understanding a languages API is a general key for writing good code.

```
string base_convert ( string $number , int $frombase , int $tobase )
```

Returns a string containing number represented in base tobase. The base in which number is given is specified in frombase. Both frombase and tobase have to be between 2 and 36, inclusive. Digits in numbers with a base higher than 10 will be represented with the letters a-z, with a meaning 10, b meaning 11 and z meaning 35.

Now let `$number` be the number you want to convert:

- If you want to convert it from ternary to decimal you use `base_convert($number, 3, 10);`
- If you want to convert it from decimal to ternary you use `base_convert($number, 10, 3);`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this can be done with [`base_convert()`](http://php.net/base_convert):

As the PHP Manual says:

> `base_convert` — Convert a number between **arbitrary** bases

So, the following would work:

```
base_convert($someinteger, 3, 10);
```

As a function:

```
function some_func($someinteger) {
    return base_convert($someinteger, 3, 10);
}
```